# Facebook 'Continue' button misplaced in Chrome Extension oauth popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, facebook-oauth, hello.js

I'm using **chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow** to start the login flow and when the user oauths with Facebook, the bottom 'Continue' button is partially out of the view. When the user has to enter an email and password for the first time, it's fine, but when Facebook asks only for the password the next time, the issue occurs. Also on the 'Forgotten you password?' page.

Since chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow doesn't allow to set size, and **resizing the window manually moves the button, but at the same misplaced position**, I see it as a clear sign that it's Facebook's code or the chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow's window's quirk.

When opening up the same auth url in a real browser window, the button is placed at the right place.

**Anyone else came across this issue?** Is there any good workaround?

[image]

Comment: Can you test this on the Chrome Canary build?

Comment: @Xan, it's the same. The bottom footer wrapper div is positioned position:absolute and bottom:0, with no fixed/relative/absolute positioned parent, which means it aligns itself to the body's bottom. Maybe this special window launched by chrome.identity might miscalculate the document height by 28pixels - this is the amount what's missing from the footer div. 

What's interesting is that the header of this special window is exactly 28px high. Any chance that's the reason the body is shifted by that amount?

Comment: Measures of the mentioned distances: https://imgur.com/wGmClWD

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking, misreported size to the page. Sounds like a Chrome bug, so check crbug.com to see if it's reported yet

Comment: @Xan, checked it and reported myself, let's see where it goes: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=885130&can=2&q=launchwebauthflow&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: @Xan, yes, forgot to copy it, but edited my comment above and included the link.